# How to make a bash script that creates 40 simultaneous instances of a program?

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I am new to `bash` and `Linux`.
I have a program I have written that I want to create multiple simultaneous instances of.

Right now, I do this by opening up 10 new terminals, and then running the program 10 times (the command I run is `php /home/calculatedata.php`

What is the simplest way to do this using a bash script?
Also, I need to know how to kill the instances because they are running an infinite loop.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a loop and start the processes in the background with `&`:

```
for (( i=0; i<40; i++ )); do
   php /home/calculatedata.php &
done
```

If these processes are the only instances of PHP you have running and you want to kill them all, the easiest way is [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall):

```
killall php
```

Comment: so in this case, the program is "php"?

Comment: @chris: yes, it would be php with the script name as parameter. (I updated he answer)

Answer (score 5):

```
for instance in {1..40}
do
  php myscript &
done
```

Answer (score 4):

How about running the php process in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=40;i+=1)); do
  php /home/calculatedata.php &
done
```

You can terminate all the instances of these background running PHP process by issuing:

```
killall php
```

Make sure you don't have any other php processes running, as they too will be killed. 
If you have many other PHP processes, then you do something like:

```
ps -ef | grep /home/calculatedata.php | cut_the_pid | kill -9
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have the `seq(1)` program (there are chances that you have it), you can do it in a slightly more readable way, like this:

```
for n in $(seq 40); do
   mycmd &
done
```

In this case the `n` variable isn't used.
Hope this helps.

Comment: you can use brace expansion to simulate seq. {1..40}

Comment: When I said "more readable" I meant more readable than the C-like for loops. The form with {1..40} is at least as readable, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the instances with a simple loop and a terminating "&" to run each job in the background:

```
INSTANCES=40
for ((i=0; $i<$INSTANCES; ++i))
do
    mycmd &
done
```

Comment: thanks, is there a simple way to terminate the script's instances all at once?

Answer (score -1):

This script is a loop that creates instances of the 'while true; do :' loop. It continues making jobs until it's cancelled, and all of the jobs run in the background. 
You can add variables for index counter and change : to your code.

`while true; do while true; do :; done & done`

to stop:

`killall bash`