# Run a PHP script multiple times simultaneously linux command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I need to test some locking in my PHP script and need to run it many times at the same time.

I remember I found a simple command to do that some time ago when I was testing MySQL locking, but can't remember the function and can't find it again. I'm running Ubuntu Linux 14.04.1.

I'm looking for a simple command without any loops.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe `&` will do the trick. Did you try `php script1.php & php script1.php & php script1.php` ?

Comment: the problem is i need to run it at least 50 times and later maybe 1000 times, that's why that won't work but thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a bash script that creates 40 simultaneous instances of a program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220030/how-to-make-a-bash-script-that-creates-40-simultaneous-instances-of-a-program)

Comment: I tried using `&` to run 50 but it didn't run a most of them.

Comment: Karl, I've seen a couple of those, but there's some simple command without any loops.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to run a command N times in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737740/is-there-a-better-way-to-run-a-command-n-times-in-bash)

Comment: Avalanche, I've noted that it doesn't use loops and got the answer already, please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use AB testing in linux

run this command

```
ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://yourpage.php
```

where -n 1000 means 1000 times to run it

and where -c 5 means you are going to do 5 concurrent processes

if you want to automate it to happen on its own activate a curl in a cron job

```
45 11 * * * /usr/bin/curl -G 127.0.0.1/yourscript.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

this will run it every day at 11 45 am

See this page for more details about AB testing or benchmark testing in linux

[Linux Benchmarking](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html)

Comment: to add it to a cron job type in : EDITOR=nano crontab -e into your command line and then add that there and save it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to run your script multiple times:

```
cmd="..some command..."; for i in $(seq 5); do $cmd; sleep 1; done
```

For instance, this:

```
cmd="ls"; for i in $(seq 5); do $cmd; sleep 1; done
```

will list files in the current directory 5 times with one second in between.

Change the command to execute the script you need to, and change the `$(seq 5)` to how ever many times you want to run the command.

e.g

```
cmd="php my_script.php"; for i in $(seq 1000); do $cmd; sleep 1; done
```